# How can I disable apache mods using puppet apache module

Tags: apache2, puppet

Enabling is easy by including the apache class and then just doing a:

```
apache::mod  { 'rewrite': }
```

This enables rewrite module for apache.

How can i disable it using puppet? I cannot seem to find any documentation on it. Is it even possible with puppetlabs apache module. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Puppet 3.7.3

Comment: Can you explain your scenario a bit? the `puppetlabs` `apache` module contains a convenience class for enabling the `rewrite` module. `include apache::mod::rewrite`, just don't include it if you don't want the rewrite module enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, add

```
class { 'apache':
  default_mods        => false,
  default_confd_files => false,
}
```

And then explicitly enable the modules that you do want.